# Rails convert binary string to .docx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ms-word

I am working in rails and I downloaded a word document from OneDrive through graph API and it returns a binary string which is a collection of files. I need to convert this string into .docx file and if I save it in a simple way or I write as a binary file after decoding it using base64, it doesn't save in the right format, it looks some awkward content in the file.
Any help in this regard will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you not just save the binary string to a file?

```
data = <binary string>

File.open('document.docx', 'wb') do |f|
  f.write(data)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

A docx file is actually a gzipped collection of files, with the file extension .docx substituted for .gz. There should be no conversion necessary, and there should be no encoding necessary in order to download it across the 'net.

You should be able to change the file extension to .gz and then unzip it using gunzip, with the result being a collection of xml files (text) and directories. If you can't do this, then you haven't correctly decoded it, so you should figure out what encoding you have requested, and reverse that, or better, don't request encoding at all.